# No square after draw call and no errors

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl

I'm trying to setup an OpenGL project for a 2D physics engine I plan to make, however I'm unable to successfully create an "Entity" class with a draw method. A window pops up with the background color specified in the render loop, but nothing else. There are no errors, so it's difficult for me to debug.

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45MIykWJ-C4&t=5480s) for guidance on the abstraction, with some differences because I don't need textures or 3D.

VAO.cpp

```
#include "VAO.h"

VAO::VAO() {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &ID);
};

void VAO::LinkAttrib(VBO& VBO, GLuint layout, GLuint numComponents, GLenum type, GLsizeiptr stride, void* offset) {
    VBO.Bind();
    glVertexAttribPointer(layout, numComponents, type, GL_FALSE, stride, offset);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(layout);
    VBO.Unbind();
};

void VAO::Bind() {
    glBindVertexArray(ID);
};

void VAO::Unbind(){
    glBindVertexArray(0);
};

void VAO::Delete() {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &ID);
};
```

VBO.cpp

```
#include "VBO.h"

VBO::VBO(std::vector<glm::vec3>& vertices) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &ID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
};

void VBO::Bind() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ID);
}

void VBO::Unbind() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void VBO::Delete() {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ID);
}
```

EBO.cpp

```
#include "EBO.h"

EBO::EBO(std::vector<GLuint>& indices) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &ID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size()*sizeof(GLuint), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void EBO::Bind() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ID);
}
void EBO::Unbind() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
void EBO::Delete() {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ID);
}
```

Entity.cpp

```
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(std::vector<glm::vec3>& vertices, std::vector<GLuint>& indices) {
    Entity::vertices = vertices;
    Entity::indices = indices;

    vao.Bind();

    VBO vbo(vertices);
    EBO ebo(indices);

    vao.LinkAttrib(vbo, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(glm::vec3), (void*)0);

    vao.Unbind();
    vbo.Unbind();
    ebo.Unbind();
}

void Entity::Draw(Shader& shader)
{
    shader.Activate();
    vao.Bind();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &indices);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stb/stb_image.h>

#include "Entity.h"

const unsigned int width = 800;
const unsigned int height = 800;

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

glm::vec3 vertices[] ={
    glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f), //Lower left
    glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f), //Upper left
    glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f), //Lower right
    glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f)  //Upper right
};

// Indices for vertices order
GLuint indices[] =
{
    0,1,2,
    1,2,3
};

int main() {

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Physics", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize OpenGL window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    gladLoadGL();

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    
    
    Shader shaderProgram("default.vert", "default.frag");

    GLuint uniID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "scale");

    shaderProgram.Activate();

    std::vector <glm::vec3> verts(vertices, vertices + sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(glm::vec3));
    std::vector <GLuint> ind(indices, indices + sizeof(indices) / sizeof(GLuint));

    Entity square(verts, ind);
    

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glClearColor(0.11f, 0.11f, 0.11f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

        shaderProgram.Activate();
        glUniform1f(uniID, 0.5f);

        square.Draw(shaderProgram);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    
    shaderProgram.Delete();

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window d imensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

default.vert

```
#version 330 core
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

uniform float scale;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x + aPos.x * scale, aPos.y + aPos.y * scale, aPos.z + aPos.z * scale, 1.0);
    //gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x,aPos.y,aPos.z,1.0);
}
```

default.frag

```
#version 330 core
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

// Outputs colors in RGBA
out vec4 FragColor;

// Inputs the color from the Vertex Shader
in vec3 color;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(0.50f,0.06f,0.87f, 1.0f);
}
```

That should be all the relevant files. I can't spot why it's not rendering. Thanks!

Comment: You're calling `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback` in a loop, what am I reading here lol

Comment: You cannot unbind an EBO after unbinding the VAO, because the EBO is stated in the VAO. The EBO and VBO behave completely different. Anyway, it is absolutely not necessary to "unbind" anything.